# i am having problem with resources and it says " Invalid resource directory name"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

C:\Users\sheharyar\AndroidStudioProjects\JoinMe\app\src\main\res\values-medium: Error: Invalid resource directory name

Comment: created new layout file for existing layout file and then set tthe value to values-medium. than after running it gave this error than on deleting the newly created layout.xml file it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-medium` is not an [available resource set qualifier](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources). Remove `-medium` from the directory name.

Comment: @SheharyarJaved: In Android Studio, right-click over the directory and choose "Delete" from the context menu. Or, use your desktop OS file manager to delete it. Or, use the command line to delete it.